# Font-size not applied to <h2> element in Outlook 2010

Tags: css, html-email, outlook-2010

I have a `font-size: 14px !important` applied to both the `h2` and the `a` elements in the following markup: `<h2><a href="#">Content</a></h2>`. However this heading appears gigantic (like a default `h2` heading) in Outlook 2010. Clearly the `font-size` rule isn't applied. But why?

Here's a more complete portion of my code:

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
   <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
      <th style="Margin:0;color:#686868;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.2;margin:0;padding:0;padding-bottom:0!important;text-align:left">
         <h2 class="small-text-center" style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:10px;color:#063972!important;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,sans-serif!important;font-size:14px!important;font-weight:700!important;line-height:1.2;margin:0;margin-bottom:0!important;padding:0;text-align:left;word-wrap:normal"><a href="http://www.lefigaro.fr" class="supplement_titre" style="Margin:0;color:#063972!important;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,sans-serif!important;font-size:14px!important;font-weight:700!important;line-height:1.2;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">L'opposition projet de loi El Khomri ne faiblit pas</a></h2>
      </th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Drake, did other styles got any effect ?just to make sure that the issue is with the font-size :)

Comment: I don't have the ability to test this, but trying changing `font-size:14px!important;` to `font-size: 14px !important;` (Added space)

Comment: Yes the rest of the styles work well. @Lucas I use Foundation For Emails who generates this inline code without space before !important. If they do that then I think this is unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: Just curious - is it important that it's an H2? I tend to avoid header tags and paragraph tags in email for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, **remove the `<h2>` and just use the `<a href>` by itself**, putting all inline styles in the anchor tag. This will negate any default styling that Outlook (and any other email client) put on default tags such as `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<p>`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot reply to @Ted Goas's response, here's my explanation.

For whatever reason, Outlook disregard the styling you have set on the `<h2>` tag even if you added `!important`, it just doesn't take it.

To iterate on what Ted Goas has said, I agree that using heading tags results in very unexpected outcomes in Outlook.

The best solution is to set the styling on the `<a>` and while we're at it, also wrap your text around a `<span>` tag as this solves color issues in Outlook too.

Below is the code I edited to solve this problem in Outlook 2010:

---

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
        <th style="Margin:0;color:#063972!important;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,sans-serif!important;font-size:14px!important;font-weight:700!important;line-height:1.2;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">
            <a href="http://www.lefigaro.fr" class="supplement_titre" style="Margin:0;color:#063972!important;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,sans-serif!important;font-size:14px!important;font-weight:700!important;line-height:1.2;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none"><span style="Margin:0;color:#063972!important;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,sans-serif!important;font-size:14px!important;font-weight:700!important;line-height:1.2;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">L'opposition projet de loi El Khomri ne faiblit pas</span></a>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Outlook 2010**

---

[image: Outlook 2010]